# How to tune EGit for large repositories?

Tags: egit, jgit

### The problem:

I find EGit great and use it intensively, but it can be incredibly slow. It can get frustrating when it takes several minutes to complete operations that the C version of git (Cgit) does in less than a couple of seconds.

All operations are significantly slower than Cgit. For example switching branches will take 10's of seconds compared to near instant. A rebase can take several minutes compared to less than a couple of seconds.

### Some details:

History size: 10114 commits  as reported with: `git rev-list HEAD --count`

Current Working directory size: 63.7 MB

Current .git size: 77.4 MB

Largest file size: 4.0 MB

OS: Linux - CentOS 5.5

File System: ext3

JVM: Oracle - Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)

EGit and JGit version: 3.0.0.201306101825-r

I was previously running 2.3 but did not notice any change in performance after upgrading.

### Could suitable window cache settings help:

I found the following quote in JGit's bugzilla [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=344143#c16):

> ...EGit had to expose UI to allow users to configure it when working on
>   bigger repositories.

Which sounds like it fits my case. So I looked around in eclipse and under `Window -> Preferences -> Team -> Git` found these Git Window Cache settings:

[image: EGit Window Cache Settings]

But how do I use them?

What do the different controls actually do? Has anyone had any success in getting EGit to be more responsive by using them?

Comment: More information is needed to provide an answer for this. What version of EGit and JGit are you using? What do you mean by "big" repository, long history or many big files (how many MB)? And maybe most important, what operations are slow (examples of what you do)?

Comment: Hi @robinst thanks for the suggesions. I've added more details to the question. hmm I forgot to add versions. Will do that now...

Comment: How many projects (with how many files) do you have? Do you have the "Refresh" options enabled in preferences > General > Workspace? Is the repository publicly accessible? If not, maybe we could arrange a private transfer so I could look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EGit 3.5.0 will bring huge performance fix for large repositories - without "tuning" anything. See https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=440722

You can use nightly EGit build update site to get the fix immediately:
http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly

Comment: I'm going to accept this answer. Back when I asked the question I tried quite a bit of tuning but never had any success with improving the performance.  Somewhere between version 3.0.0  and 3.7.1, my performance issues went away :)

Comment: This is no longer a terribly useful answer. Egit 4.2.0 was released in December 2016 and there is still a need to manually tune the Window Cache parameters to get egit to run smoothly with large numbers of large repositories with long histories.

Answer (score 4):

## Recommendations

As [Matthias Sohn suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896523/42473), the *Window cache limit* appears to be most significant of these parameters.

For me, increasing this from "10 m" to "500 m" made a huge difference to how responsive egit was.

## Details of each parameter

From the source code<sup>†</sup> of [WindowCacheConfig.java](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/storage/file/WindowCacheConfig.java):

#### Windows Size

> *packedGitWindowSize*: size in bytes of a single window mapped or read in from the pack file

Default: 8 k

#### Window cache limit

> *packedGitLimit*: maximum number bytes of heap memory to dedicate to caching pack file data.

Default: 10 m

#### Delta base cache limit

> *deltaBaseCacheLimit*: maximum number of bytes to cache in delta base cache for inflated, recently accessed objects, without delta chains.

Default: 10 m

#### Stream File Threshold

> *streamFileThreshold*: the size threshold beyond which objects must be streamed.
>
> Objects smaller than this size can be obtained as a contiguous byte array, while objects bigger than this size require using anObjectStream.

Default: 50 m

#### Use virtual memory mapping

> **packedGitMMAP**: true enables use of Java NIO virtual memory mapping for windows; false reads entire window into a byte[] with standard read calls.

Default: Unchecked

#### Not presented on the preferences page

> *packedGitOpenFiles*: maximum number of streams to open at a time. Open packs count against the process limits.

Default: 128

---

<sup>† Thanks [Jens Theeß](https://stackoverflow.com/users/419440/jens-thee%C3%9F) for their comment on [Matthias Sohn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19896523/42473) containing a pointer to the source code.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

- increase the window cache limit to a larger value, it's defining the size of jgit's cache used to map pack files into memory
- do you run gc (either from egit or native git) on your repository ? JGit/EGit don't run it automatically (yet). YOu may check the number of loose object in EGit's repositories view (click "Properties" and select tab "Statistics")
- how many commits does your repository have (age in year doesn't say anything since it could have an age of 10 years with 2 commits or 2 mio commits)
- which OS / filesystem are you using ?

Comment: Hello Mattias, Thanks for the suggestions. I've added the details you asked for to the question and will try out you suggestions...

Comment: I would like to see an explanation on the different memory settings as well. I'm not sure what to increase and how much to improve my EGit performance.

Comment: I've found some hints in the source: https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/storage/file/WindowCacheConfig.java

Comment: I've added [an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42788203/42473) @T3rm1 which includes details from the [source code](https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/blob/master/org.eclipse.jgit/src/org/eclipse/jgit/storage/file/WindowCacheConfig.java), as suggested by Jens Theeß.